# Focusable Button in Listview

Tags: android, listview, focusable

For a ListView with custom row layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnBin"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/ktape" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     android:text="Temporary"
    android:id="@+id/txtShowUsername"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="right"
       android:paddingRight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the button should not be focusable to let the ListView's OnItemClickListener execute:

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Why do I need to set the focusable to false? why a focusable button prevents `OnItemClickListener.OnItemClick()` to execute?

Comment: What happens? is it working the item click listener?

Comment: @Raghunandan, I want to know why I need to set the focusable to false.

Comment: You can look at the source code and find out the why part

Answer (score 1):

When you touch something on the screen, the touch gesture is get by the root view of your layout. Then it passes the touch gesture to its child one by one until it is consumed. If the child is a clickable view, then it consumes the touch gesture and returns true. So that the touch gesture will not be passed to other Views. If the child is not a clickable View, then it just returns false, the touch gesture will be passed to next children.

Finally, if no child view consumes the touch gesture, it will be sent back to the parent itself. Now the parent can consume the touch gesture, if it has any.

Now in your case, ListView is parent and Button is the child. First, ListView passes the touch gesture to the button. Since button is a clickable View by default, it consumes the touch gesture, so the OnItemClickListener of ListView will not work. By explicitly setting focusable, focusableInTouchMode, clickable as false, the button becomes non clickable View. So the button wont consume the touch gesture, and the OnItemClickListener of ListView works.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You know by setting focusable to false I can have clickListener for button and itemClickListener for list items and it works well.  In short, the button is still clickable.

Comment: Ideally, when you tap on the button, the ClickListener of button will work and the OnItemClickListener of ListView will not triggered. When you tap on the ListView item(not on the Button), the ListView OnItemClickListener will work, and the ClickListener of Button will not triggered.

Comment: I think, instead of android:focusable="false", you should add the attribute android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the root layout of the ListView item. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3adescendantFocusability

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: This code works, I want to know why I need to set the focusable to false.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think if you don't when you click the button when focusable is true and clickable is false nothing happens (not even onitemclick from listview)

Comment: Yes that is true. But I want to know why?